# Dealing with dropped frames in background plate when doing keyframe animation in After Effects

Tags: video, after-effects, editing, keyframes

I am working on a video which includes some dropped frames ever so often. When a frame dropped, it repeated the previous frame sometimes 2 or 3 times. I am overlaying many objects on this video, and the problem is that when interpolating a property, it continues to interpolate during the dropped frames, meaning the objects move while the video remains still. Because of the huge amount of objects in my scene (100+) it is incredibly tedious to go through each and find each dropped frame, set a keyframe for the properties, and copy them for all the repetitions of that frame. Is there a way to either set a keyframe for all properties at some time, or ideally to set time ranges for the whole composition where interpolation is disabled?

Comment: Posting as a comment since I don't have a full solution for you, but your best bet is going to be to interpolate new frames or alter your frame rate so you can drop out the frames in a custom pulldown.  Neither are particularly easy unless you have software to automate it and I don't know what options are available for that right now.  If you get the footage fixed though, then the problem goes away and it will lessen the frame stutter as well.

Comment: @AJHenderson I can write a program to remove duplicate frames, but I worry that this will then cause audio sync issues due to the amount of removed frames. Should I go down this route?

Comment: no you don't want to simply remove them.  You need to actually interpolate a frame to go in their place.  It's often possible to blend frames to get an approximation of what the frame would have looked like that is good enough to avoid a noticeable microstutter in the footage.  It's been a long time since I've used such software though and I'm not sure what current options are.

Comment: If you turn the video into an image sequence and delete the dupe frames, you could use imagemagick to create an interpolated frame using morph. https://is.gd/RIgHae I've done that for video where there were lost frames, I just used shell scripting to detect the missing ones from the numerical sequence, and morphed them to gether to create a new intermediate.

Answer (score 0):

Try frame blending.

- Show the switch column in timeline.
- Check, and enable the Frame Blending switch on the timeline.
- Check, and enable the Frame Blending option of the layer.
- Always check your composition frame rate.

Shortcut:
<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>k</kbd> (Win) or <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>k</kbd> (Mac)